# How do I update selenium-webdriver if I haven't installed it globally?

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I installed `selenium-webdriver` using `npm install selenium-webdriver` without the `-g` option. All the docs say to run `webdriver-manager update` but this does not work since I installed it locally.

How do I update the webdriver if it is installed locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, is you can just delete your `./node_modules/selenium-webdriver` by doing

```
$ rm -fr ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver
$ npm install selenium-webdriver
```

Which will, of course, fetch and install the latest locally.

Comment: My question is not properly worded. I actually wanted to install `protractor`... whatever, I'll leave the question and the answer because it's correct. I think just using `npm install` will also do updates if package.json does not have a precise version (I'm not sure).

Comment: it's possible that just running `npm install selenium-webdriver` will update it without having to do the `rm -fr` but much like you said, i'm not sure either `:)`